# Why does my dynamic form submit not use the jQuery-replaced button label value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<button class="gocrazy" label="1"/>
<button class="gocrazy" label="2"/>
<button class="gocrazy" label="3"/>

<form id="crazyform" method="POST" action="/crazyform">
<input type="hidden" id="crazyreplace" value="REPLACE WITH BUTTON LABEL ON CLICK">
</form>

$(".gocrazy").button();

$(".gocrazy").click( function(event)
{   
    var gocrazy = $(this).attr("label");
    $("#crazyreplace").val(gocrazy);
    $("form#crazyform").submit();
    return false;
});
```

I want to submit this form with a value replaced from the button label (1, 2 or 3) into the hidden `crazyreplace` field using jQuery.

But the form is submitted with the original text message (`REPLACE WITH BUTTON LABEL ON CLICK`).

What is wrong here?

Comment: What is the value of gocrazy? It might be `undefined`.

Comment: your code works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/hYkMt/1/

Comment: Oh, but it's important to note that your `<input>` does need a "name" attribute added.  I assumed that you just left that off of the code you posted here.

Comment: As others have observed, this code (other than missing the name attribute on the hidden field) seems to work perfectly well.  If this is a simplified demo, you may have accidentally removed the buggy code in the process.  If not, could you provide some additional context?  What does your server-side code look like? How did you come to the conclusion that the original message is submitted?  Could you create a jsFiddle/jsBin demo that reproduces the bug?

Answer (score 1):

Check working example http://jsfiddle.net/TM7Hp/3/

Comment: That example doesn't work. The input still has no name. Why is it hiding on JSFiddle anyway? Isn't there a FAQ somewhere about answers being answers and not just links to other sites?

Comment: This is for the sake of showing that label gets transferred to the input.

Answer (score -2):

Given that code, the form won't be submitted with **any** text message. The input doesn't have a `name` so it cannot be a successful control.

If you want to submit the value of a clicked button, do it like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="/crazyform">
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="1">
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="2">
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="3">
</form>
```

Only the clicked submit button will be successful, so the server will receive

```
button=2
```

if you submit it using the button with value 2.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. It is hard to tell what the point actually is. The literal question cannot be answered as it is based on a false premise (probably because we've been provided with a reduced test case that fails to reproduce the original problem).

Comment: If the "name" attribute is added to the posted code, however, it does actually work.

Comment: @David - I think you are mistaken.  The name of the button control is irrelevant, as the form is being submitted programmatically by jQuery. However, the hidden input DOES need a name in order for it to be sent with the form submission. See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/94KdG/

Comment: @Pointy — Only if  you take out the attempt to call the non-existent `button()` method on the jQuery object (unless that is new in jQuery after the version I grabbed to test it). If you fix that as well then the described bug still won't appear.

Comment: @Ender — Whoops, I did mean the hidden input.

Comment: @David - `.button()` is a method of jQueryUI, I think Greg just neglected to mention that he's using it as well.

Comment: @Ender — Ah. The point stands though. We can't reproduce the described bug.

Comment: @David Dorward the ".button()" thing is the jQuery UI "fancy buttons" plugin. I suspected that it was what was responsible for things not working, but in fact it all seems to work just as posted.

Comment: @David - Agreed.  I think there is something else going on here that cannot be divined from the provided code.